# Centos official base docker image running out of space

Tags: centos, yum, docker

I thought docker images use the underlying filesystem to create their own filesystem. However, I am installing some packages through "rvm requirements" that results in an error.

The error is Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/centosplus/packages

I wonder whats the problem here.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this exact error on Windows (8.1) while trying to run a new `Dockerfile` with `docker-machine`. The fix for me was to remove all dangling docker images to free up some space on the docker VM.

Executing `docker ps -qa` will list all dangling images:

`fa2c0a66ee94
e815198f0d6e
...
7e925483e67f
e524267e8a9a`

Executing `docker rm $(docker ps -qa)` will reclaim the space used by dangling images:

`$ docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
fa2c0a66ee94
e815198f0d6e
...
7e925483e67f
e524267e8a9a`

Answer (score 2):

Check the disk space available on the host machine/VM for directory /tmp using `df -h` and `ls -la /`.

If you are using docker-machine (OSX), then you might want to create a larger host VM with `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size 50000 [name]`.

Comment: In newer versions of docker on macOS you can change the amount of space set aside for the disk image in Docker -> Disk. Increasing the space available to docker fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk has insufficient space.

Look over on the right under related - lots of good information there.

Comment: It is running on a container. The container uses the underlying disk which is almost emoty. I will look into the related links though

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers mentioned here worked for me. Then, I stumbled upon a prune command, which indeed worked for me..

`docker system prune -a`

This will delete:

- all stopped containers
- all volumes not used by at least one container
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all images without at least one container associated to them

I was able to free up ~5 GB and this command should definitely work.